# How to use mean value theorem to get the inequality $|\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}|\le \frac{|s|}{n^{\sigma+1}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: Stein173]

How to use the mean-value theorem to get the inequality $|\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}|\le \frac{|s|}{n^{\sigma+1}}$?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = x^{-s}$ then $f'(x) = -sx^{-s-1}$.

MVT: take $[n,x]$, with $x\leq n+1$, then $\frac{f(n)-f(x)}{1} = f'(y)$ for some $y \in (n,x)$.

Restated this is $\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s} = \frac{-s}{y^{1+s}}$.

We have:

$|\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{x^s}| \leq \frac{|s|}{y^{1+s}}$.

To finish this off, we can say that $y^{1+s} = n^{1+\sigma}$ with $|\sigma| >|s|$.

Comment: more to do, $s$ complex.

Comment: Can you use the mean-value theorem to get the inequality?

Comment: Well of course you can, it says so in the notes

Comment: But I don't know how to do?

Comment: have another look at what I've written

Comment: I think it supposes $\Re(s)>0$ in Proposition 2.5, doesn't it?